# Converting recursive formula of complex sequence to explicit formula

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How do you convert the recursive formula $t_1=1, t_n=2\times t_{n-1}+1 $ into an explicit formula (without using a system of equations or writing out the values)?

Comment: There are a number of ways.  You should look into the search terms "linear recurrence", "characteristic equation", "homogenous solution", and "particular solution" for problems like the one you posted.  A full treatise on the topic should be included in many textbooks that cover recurrence relations and would be too detailed to include everything here.  Suffice to say, based on the characteristic equation and the nonhomogenous part, we know it will be of the form $t_n = c_1\cdot 2^n + c_2$ which we can then solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$ to get $t_n = 2^n-1$

Comment: Writing out the first $5$ terms should give you a pretty good clue.

Comment: Writing out the first term will be sufficient.

Comment: Hint: express the values in binary.

Comment: @hardmath what is sₙ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible answers to your question, even with your specific requirement

> (without using a system of equations or writing out the values)?

From the recursion it is clear that the sequence will
be approximately the powers of $2$ with possibly a factor and a constant added or subtracted. Thus we 
need to determine the two constants. You already have given $\,t_1=1\,$ and the simplest possible expression 
(other than $\,2^n\,$ or $\,2^n+1\,$) which it 
possibly could be is $\,t_n := 2^n-1\,$
which satisfies both equations and we are done.

In general, you will usually need to use systems of equations and 
there are multiple sources of information about solving these
kinds of linear recurrence equations with constant coefficients.